# Positive semidefinite matrices and polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is positive semidefinite and if $p(t)$ is any polynomial such that $p(t) > 0$ for $t \geq 0$, show that $p(A)$ is positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 3):

The matrix $A$ is triangularisable in $\mathbb{C}$ and its eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ are non negative, hence there's an invertible matrix $P$ such that 
$A= PTP^{-1}$
so $p(A)=Pp(T)P^{-1}$ and the eigenvalues of $p(A)$ are $p(\lambda_i)>0$, then the matrix $p(A)$ is definite positive.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $A$ is similar to $D$ then $p(A)$ is similar to $p(D)$.